# Answer file for clonable windows installation

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, answer-file

I would like to create a windows image that can be cloned to multiple different computers, with different (known) hardware. And I would like Windows to resize the partitions after cloning. I read that you should "sysprep /generalize" from audit mode before cloning an image.

Now my question is, can I just install windows normally and interrupt the installation before the specialize step, in order to make a copy? Or do I have to let it proceed into OOBE, then enter audit mode, and then generalize manually? Whats the simplest scheme to achive this?

Things that are confusing me:

- Can I do everything from one answer file, or do I have to create separate autounattend.xml and unattend.xml like in [this tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96683-create-media-automated-unattended-install-windows-10-a.html)? How do I chain them then?
- There is `<Generalize ForceShutDownNow="true" Mode="OOBE" />` which seems to let me interrupt the installation, but it only goes in the `5 auditSystem` block. So that means I will go twice through generalize? I want to use `ExtendOSPartition`, which only makes sense in `4 specialize` (after cloning)... But if I go twice though generalize, then I need to run this only the second time (`unattend.xml`)... but to achive this I'd have to go through audit mode and call sysprep manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you instructs Windows Setup to switch to Audit Mode (OOBE pass in autounattend.xml), the system will automatically copy autounattend.xml to C:\Windows\Panther and **rename** it to unattend.xml which will be used as answer file for Sysprep, which eventually cause issues. Hence, we should have separate autounattend.xml and unattend.xml.

The procedure:

a. We enable Pass 7 OOBE> Reseal> Audit. Seeing this part, Windows will jump to Pass 5 "auditSystem" and Pass 6 "auditUser".

b. In auditUser pass, you can run your customization scripts and let the last script to run sysprep using your specified unattend.xml (which includes the ExtendOSPartition tag), i.e.:
`sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown /unattend:c:\windows\system32\sysprep\unattend.xml`

A more detailed and advanced guide can be found at:
https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/modern-os-deployment-mosd/